# Computationally check for roots/positiveness of a big polynomial in a given interval

Tags: polynomials, roots, computational-mathematics, sagemath, python

For a proof, I need to check that given a little interval $(0, 0.28)$
some concrete polynomials $\in \mathbb{Q}[w]$ (polynomials in one variable ranging over the real numbers, with degrees around 50) are positive there, or equivalently that they have no roots in the same interval (since evaluating in 0 I get a positive value).

Taking this into account, what would you recommend me to do? I was considering Sturm algorithm, but I am open to suggestions and orientation.

As for the language, I had thought of Python, but I wouldn't mind using Sage, C, Java...

Comment: How fast does it need to be? If the answer is "not especially", then a straightforward procedure would be to compute the eigenvalues of the companion matrix of your polynomial, which for a $50 \times 50$ matrix would be pretty fast. Moreover it is built into basically any numerical package.

Comment: Well, the faster the better since I will be running it a few times, that is a good option. Given its a small interval I was wondering if there was a better option than computing all of the roots.

Comment: Unfortunately, it's possible to have a great deal of oscillation in that small interval for certain polynomials, and that oscillation will hinder standard root-finding methods. So doing anything useful "locally" will require some knowledge about the relative size of the coefficients. Do you know that in advance (even just approximately)?

Comment: Yes, I am computing the polynomials at the moment so I don't have the exact coefficients yet, but they are mostly big rational numbers such as $$\frac{95500476033817592129}{32768}.$$

Comment: The only thing that matters is the *relative* size, so that you know in what region each term competes significantly with the other terms. Also, I should add that being concerned about the speed of computing all roots of a degree 50 polynomial using an eigenvalue routine is *probably* premature optimization. In Matlab I can run that task in less than 5 ms for a randomly chosen polynomial, including construction.

Comment: I see, thanks a lot. I will work on it and see how far I go.